# PHP - Convert date to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: php, date, time

I was wondering if it was possible to format todays date to below format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

It's important that the "T" is preserved, like this:

```
2017-07-20T00:00:00
```

Below I have:

```
$invoice_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I can't figure out how to add the "T" in between.

Comment: explode, add T, implode

Comment: @ArtOsi who hurt you? D:

Comment: `date( DATE_W3C );` would have done also. But you're stuck with a timezone as an extra to it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`T` is a *format character* so you can't use it directly. Escape it (`\T`) to get a literal `T` character:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash.

```
$invoice_date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$invoice_date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can create an object of the **DateTime** and set the **Timezone**. You can see a list of Timezone strings here. http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
$invoice_date =  (new \DateTime('America/New_York'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');

echo $invoice_date;
```

Hope this helps