# How can I change my date to this format?

Tags: php, date, datetime, odata

I currently have a date formated like this:

```
2017-11-02 11:44:24
```

However; I need it in this format: `2014-03-11T14:49:52`

This is due to the use of a RESTful API based on oData. How can I achieve this date format?

Comment: Use the `date()` function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ... bookmark that link... you will use it alot in your career! =D hint: `echo date('c',$your_ts_variable);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Convert date to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217165/php-convert-date-to-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss) You are always expected to do your research and search SO before posting a question.  This search term would have fixed you up: `[php] convert date YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS is:question`

Comment: Honestly had no idea what to search for, never used this format before haha. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for: [DateTime:createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-11-02 11:44:24');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Once you've got the DateTime object then you can format it as needed with ->format()

Answer (score 0):

The date and time can be tricky, but what you want to be sure of is the date and time for your region or Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) or Universal Time Coordinate (UTC).  Both GMT and UTC refer to the same time, but your server/database/publish date is likely in your local time.  Here's an example of what you can use for local time:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date = date('Y-m-d\TG:i:s');
echo $date;
```

This will `echo` `2017-11-02T01:02:58`.  The capital `G` represents a 24 hour time stamp, and a small `g` will represent a 12 hour time stamp.

Depending on how your server is setup, without the `date_default_timezone_set` you will get the UTC time.